# Jquery draggable list items are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, listitem

Hi i've a list item with draggable action.
When i dragged one li, the li is hidden by other list items

DEMO : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FVSs/2/)

```
$(function()
  {

      $("#drop").droppable({
          drop:function(e)
          {
              $("#drop").html("is drop");
          }
      });
      $("#down li").draggable({revert:true});
  });

<ul id="down">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="drop">
</div>
```

I want that the li item dragged would be visible over the others items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`stack` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack) to your draggable:

```
$("#down li").draggable({
    revert: true,
    stack: "li"
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5FVSs/3/)**

From the docs:

> stack:  Controls the z-index of the set of elements that match the
>   selector, always brings the currently dragged item to the front. Very
>   useful in things like window managers.

Comment: Anonymous coward downvoter care to grow a pair and explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot, Yes i haven't seen in documentation (but it's in english and it's not very comprehensive). My code is little bit complicated because, i manage the multiple drag. And the others li dragged don't appear in front of the other li. But i've add to start event in draggable:

```
 $(this).css("z-index","9999")
```

and

```
$(this).css("z-index","1")
```

to stop event in draggable with `stack:".ui-selected"` . And all my list item selected to drag appeared in front.